# Symfony 2 OneToOne relationship with missing ID

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, one-to-one, relationships

first of all, this Symfony is in 2.7.6 version and the bbdd is mysql.

my problem is that my "oneToOne" relationship fails. Fails because my tech_note_en doesn't have the "father". I think, is better with a little code...

In resume: One "tech_note" have one "tech_note_es", and one "tech_note_en", and one "tech_note_fr", ...

**TECH_NOTE**

```
class Tech_note {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Tech_note_es", mappedBy="tech_note", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * */
    private $tech_note_es;
}
```

**TECH_NOTE_ES**

```
class Tech_note_es {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Tech_note", inversedBy="tech_note_es")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tech_note_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $tech_note;
}
```

All ok, but when I make the "persist" I have something like this:

```
Tech_note
   id
  5236

Tech_note_es
id    | tech_note_id
224   |   NULL
```

If I change the null for 5236, all works correctly. But I think this ID is provided by doctrine/orm, isn't it? Or I'm wrong and I need to use "setters/getters" to make manually the relationship in my controller action?

**SOLUTION**

```
class Tech_note {
    /**
     * Set techNoteEs
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tech_note_es $techNoteEs
     *
     * @return Tech_note
     */
    public function setTechNoteEs(\AppBundle\Entity\Tech_note_es $techNoteEs = null) {
        $techNoteEs->setTechNote($this);
        $this->tech_note_es = $techNoteEs;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set techNoteEn
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tech_note_en $techNoteEn
     *
     * @return Tech_note
     */
    public function setTechNoteEn(\AppBundle\Entity\Tech_note_en $techNoteEn = null) {
        $techNoteEn->setTechNote($this);
        $this->tech_note_en = $techNoteEn;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set techNoteFr
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tech_note_fr $techNoteFr
     *
     * @return Tech_note
     */
    public function setTechNoteFr(\AppBundle\Entity\Tech_note_fr $techNoteFr = null) {
        $techNoteFr->setTechNote($this);
        $this->tech_note_fr = $techNoteFr;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Thanks to all!

Roger

Comment: Yes, you need to establish the relation yourself.  A popular approach is to have Tech_note::setTech_note_es call Tech_note_es::setTech_note.  Then your controller does not have to worry about it.  And please consider following the typical class naming convention.  Tech_note should be TechNote.

Comment: HI @Cerad, first of all, thanks a lot! You solve my problem! Thanks!. In other hand I know my name class are wrong....but this is a legacy code and expensive to change now.